# Parallel rsync from remote server gets unexpected remote arg

Tags: rsync, gnu-parallel

I am trying to pull files from a remote server to my local machine using parallel. To test this, I created a directory in my remote server with two files `dummy/bla.txt, dummy/bli.txt` The following command works

```
sshpass -p "mypass" rsync -ave "ssh -p 12345" omryg@localhost:/cs/sci/omryg/dummy ./

receiving incremental file list
dummy/
dummy/bla.txt
dummy/bli.txt

sent 66 bytes  received 195 bytes  104.40 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

When I try to run with `parallel`, I first created a file `transfer.log` with two lines with the file names. Then I ran

```
sshpass -p "mypass" cat transfer.log | parallel --will-cite -j 2 rsync -ave "ssh -p 12345" omryg@localhost:/cs/sci/omryg/dummy/{} ./

Unexpected remote arg: omryg@localhost:/cs/sci/omryg/dummy/bla.txt
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1354) [sender=3.1.3]
Unexpected remote arg: omryg@localhost:/cs/sci/omryg/dummy/bli.txt
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1354) [sender=3.1.3]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to discuss here.

First the failure of the command line, second the details of this line.

#### Hypotheses regarding the origin of error

As it is, the argument `omryg@localhost:/cs/sci/omryg/dummy/bla.txt` does not seem  incorrect.

Is it possible that there are invalid non-printable characters in your file `transfer.log`?
I am thinking more specifically of wrong markers for newline. It sometimes happens when editing files in Windows (`vim` would show a character `^M` at the end of each line for example; this is called the "dos" encoding).
However, the fact that both lines are treated sequentially hints at correctly detected newline characters…

Instead of a one-liner, can you decompose your code as such

```
sshpass -p "mypass" cat transfer.log > local.log
```

and examine `local.log`? `vim` shows non-printable characters, but a more thorough search could involve `hexdump`.

```
hexdump -c local.log
```

would show the characters, 16 per line. The newline character is represented by `\n`. Note that in its vanilla usage, `hexdump` "dumps hex", i.e. outputs hexadecimal codes for characters. The option `-c` shows representations of the said characters.

If it is OK, you can try further:

```
cat local.log | parallel …
```

I could not comment below your question because my account is fresh new. I will wait for your replies and adapt my answer if needed.

#### Comments on some details of the command

1. Security concerns

In your command lines, you explicitly type your password; try creating a key exchange with the server: generate a key pair on your local machine with `ssh-keygen`, copy the content of the public key (by default `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) into the remote file `~/.ssh/known_hosts` (create it if it is absent, the bash redirection operator `>>` does that, i.e. appending to a file and creating it if absent). More about it [here](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/).
As a general comment, your password should only be stored in your brain, never in a script nor in your shell command history. I don't recommend the use of `sshpass` at all.

2. Use of `parallel` and `rsync`

Now about the use of `parallel`. It is often considered an alternative to explicit loops (while's and for's) by running the iterations in parallel. In your case, you run `rsync`, a network transfer command, in parallel. Firstly, `rsync` is optimized for sequential transfers and to analyze whole directories. Secondly, independently of the number of cpus you use, you might rather be limited by the total network bandwidth.
Using `parallel` may also have a disadvantage: the outputs of your parallelized commands are all mixed and ordered *as they are run*. It might get difficult to diagnose errors with a lot of items to process.
If you really want to constrain the list of files transferred by `rsync`, you might want to look into the option `--include-from=list.txt`, where `list.txt` is an ASCII file of patterns (so, plain filenames work), one per line. If you are sure you don't want to use patterns, there is a simpler option `--files-from=list.txt`. In that case, you only need to pass a directory as the source argument; rsync will take the files from it. More about this option in the man page, and the relevant excerpt has been cited *in extenso* [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647476/how-to-rsync-only-a-specific-list-of-files#30176688).
Finally, if you need to process 2 arguments to run on 2 cpus, you can skip the part `-j 2`; it is automatically set in your case.

3. Configuring an SSH host

I noticed that you use `localhost` and a port number `-p 12345`, which seems to indicate a local tunnel. In case you need to type this often, you can complete your local SSH configuration (`~/.ssh/config`) with a "shortcut":

```
host my-proxy
    HostName localhost
    Port 12345
    User omryg
```

and now your command line simply reads `rsync -ave 'ssh' my-proxy:/cs/sci/omryg/dummy ./`. Notice the absence of `-p 12345` and of `omryg@localhost`.