# rsync a list of files from one server to another

Tags: rsync

I am connected on server A and in a directory where I want to copy a list of files listed in `my.list` file which is right in this directory.

The `my.list` contains one line for each `path/file`.
But these are path/files **in the server B**.

Usually  to copy files from server B to server A, I do (from the place in server A where I want to copy):

```
rsync -v --progress -e "ssh -p 4410" login@adress:/path/file .
```

How can I change this line so that I don't just copy `/path/file`,  but rather all the files listed in `my.list`?

Thanks!

M

Comment: Try `grep | xargs`

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647476/how-to-rsync-only-a-specific-list-of-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rsync only a specific list of files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647476/how-to-rsync-only-a-specific-list-of-files)