# rsync's --files-from is giving error instead of syncing file

Tags: rsync

I have a directory in `$HOME/me/backup` set up like this

```
test/
file.txt
sync.txt
```

The only contents of `sync.txt` is this:

```
file.txt
```

I open my terminal, navigate to `$HOME/me/backup` and run `rsync -av --files-from=sync.txt test`.

I get this error: `rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at options.c(2433) [client=3.2.7]`.

I thought all files listed in `sync.txt` would get copied into `test/`. How do I make this happen in rsync?

Comment: Are you missing the destination from `rsync [OPTION] SRC DEST`? `rsync -av --files-from=sync.txt test` has "test" as the source but the destination is missing.

Comment: @joeljpa I thought rsync would read each line of `sync.txt` as a source and put them in the destination `test/`. Is that not the case?

Comment: No, it's not the case. We always have to mention SRC DEST when running it with any option. Now that you say it I don't blame you for assuming this. `--files-from` we treat it like any other option. Your list file only states _exactly which files to pick_ from SRC and put into DEST.
The [answer for "How to rsync only a specific list of files?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30176688/) should help, it has the man page. Tread lighly because `The filenames that are read from the FILE are all relative to the source dir` (man page). Let me know if it works or not after running it with SRC DEST.

Comment: Then we can formally conclude this. I posted my answer as per our comments. Do let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our comments, you missed adding the `SRC`.

The original command:

`rsync -av --files-from=sync.txt test`

Needs to be:

`rsync -av --files-from=sync.txt <your SRC folder> test`

In our case, `sync.txt` merely states *exactly which files to pick* from `SRC` and put into `DEST`. By itself, `--files-from` won't work or use that text file's list as your source dir. We must always put both `SRC` and `DEST` when running it with any option(s). `--files-from` is still just an option in the end.

From its entry on the man page,

> Using this option allows you to specify the exact list of files to
> transfer

Tread lightly since the filenames that are read from the `sync.txt` are all relative to the `SRC` dir. The [accepted answer for "How to rsync only a specific list of files?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30176688/) quotes the relevant parts of the man page for that and should be helpful.